# In CATIA V5 CAA, can we retrieve an approximation of a CATIGSMSpline as a CATCurve?

Tags: catia, caa

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to get an approximated equation from a **CATIGSMSpline**. Since **CATCurve** seem to have everything it needs, I search a way to convert my GSM spline as a geometrical one.

Is it even possible (with obvious loss of information at some spots, but under a certain tolerance) ? If yes, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to convert CATIGSMSpline to CATCurve.
Get CATBody for your CATPart then retrieve CATCell, CATEdge and CATCurve info

Comment: Damned, that was quite easy... I didn't figure out the way through CATCells myself, thanks !

Comment: Good..It Happens 